# Bash script that makes use of android tts

Tags: android, bash, text-to-speech

I have Android Studio installed and often develop some apps. I test them on emulators and on a real device. I know how to use `TextToSpeech`.

But I'm curious whether it is possible to create a bash script that would use Android TTS Engine to generate audio files. The signature of the script could be:

```
$ android-tts.sh <text-file> <audio-file>
```

Can android tts be accessed in a bash script somehow to accomplish this?
Maybe `adb` can run an android app and pipe it results to another app (e.g. lame). Something like:

```
$ adb <app> | lame - /tmp/text.mp3
```

Comment: so what is not working?

Comment: @Inian I have no idea whether it is doable at all. I don't know where to start. Maybe android tts related jars can be extracted and reused in a desktop app. I don't know... Do you understand? With other words can Android TTS be used outside of an Android app somehow.